# Gmail page works but won't stop loading

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, webpage

When I open the GMail page in Chrome (9.0.597.102) on OS X (10.6.4), the page works fine and is functional, but it often remains in a "Loading" state, with the loading icon active, for extremely long periods of time.

Functionally, there is no problem, since everything is accessible, and the problem is intermittent. Sometimes it immediately completes loading, other times it will claim to be "loading" for hours.

My date is correct (as set with time.*.apple.com), and I don't have any Google Labs enabled.

Does anyone else have this problem, or know the cause and solution?

Comment: does it keep that way after a page refresh?

Comment: Refreshing the page rarely has any impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two possible causes come to mind:

1. Your cache is corrupted and needs to be completely cleared (preferably while the browser is shut down, or if you can't do this at least be viewing a blank page or a page that contains only text before clearing the cache)
2. The AJAX code in JavaScript, which waits for updates from the server (so that GMail can effectively "push" updates to your web browser), is being reported by your web browser as a "download in progress" (this is technically correct, but when it comes to AJAX most web browsers exclude these communications from the "Downloading" status indicators)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Clearing the cache hasn't helped, is there a way to monitor what the AJAX code is doing?

Comment: @MLW:  There seems to be an answer to your specific question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479444/monitor-ajax-calls-via-curl